# Array mapping no longer working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, array-map

In Swift 2, I had the following struct setup:

```
struct LogInfo {
    var logNumber: Int
    var logID: String
    var species: String
    var diameter: Float
    var formClass: Int
    var numLogs: Float
    var boardFootage: Double

    static func jsonArray(array : [LogInfo]) -> [AnyObject] {
        return array.map{$0.jsonRepresentation}
    }

    var jsonRepresentation : [String: AnyObject] {
        return [
            "logNumber": String(logNumber) as AnyObject,
            "logID": logID as AnyObject,
            "species": species as AnyObject,
            "diameter": String(diameter) as AnyObject,
            "formClass": String(formClass) as AnyObject,
            "numLogs": String(numLogs) as AnyObject,
            "boardFootage": String(boardFootage) as AnyObject
        ]
    }
}
```

In this code, the method "jsonArray" in the middle of my code, returns this error:

**"Result value of type '[String: AnyObject]' does not conform to closure result type 'AnyObject'"**

As you can see from the jsonRepresentation below, the json data is going to contain an assortment of different data types.

I attempted to cast each element in the jsonRepresentation array as "AnyObject", as you can see (which xCode suggested I do in the upgrade wizard) - but I am still getting the aforementioned error with my array mapping.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply changing `[AnyObject]` to `[[String: AnyObject]]` in the **jsonArray** method would work.

It seems that you are returning **jsonRepresentation** inside the map function which is `[String: AnyObject]` instance, and Swift 3 does not implicitly convert `[String: AnyObject]` to `AnyObject` anymore.

```
static func jsonArray(array : [LogInfo]) -> [[String: AnyObject]] {
    return array.map{$0.jsonRepresentation}
}
```